# Determining type of filter given its equation

Tags: filters, transfer-function

Given a general filter equation, how can one tell the type of filter that the same equation represents? Meaning how can I know if the filter is Low/High/Band Pass etc...?

For example, the following equation:

$ y_{n} = x_{n} + x_{n-2} $

Represents a "Band Stop" filter, but why?

Comment: gonna have to apply the Z transform.  and set $z = e^{j\omega}$ to find out how this filter behaves.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson  , i see a down vote ,whats wrong with my solution if you can point out

Answer (score 2):

The $\mathcal Z$-transform of the given difference equation is :

$$H(z) = 1 + z^{-2}$$

Put $z= \exp(j\omega)$ and remember that in discrete time systems the low frequencies are at $2n\pi$ $(n=0,1,2, \ldots)$ and the high frequencies occur at $(2n+1)\pi$; this is just a consequence of the periodic behavior of the discrete time complex exponentials.

So, $H(z) = 1 + \exp(-2j\omega)$ at $z = \exp(j\omega)$.

When $\omega=0; H(z) = 2$ and $w = \pi$ gives $H(z)= 2$.

Thus, both at high and low frequencies the the system function provides same 
gain and hence the filter with the given $H(z)$ is a **BAND REJECT/ NOTCH FILTER** with $H(z) = 0$ at $\omega = \pi/2$.